# SQL Server two update locks held on the same object at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Consider this snippet from a SQL Server deadlock error log.

Version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64) 
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation        Nov 30 2018 12:57:58 
Developer Edition (64-bit)
```

It seems that two different processes hold the update lock on `PK_mytable` at the same time.

Please can anyone explain what is going on here?

My understanding is that this should be impossible....

Thanks, Keith.

```
 objectname=mydb.myschema.mytable 
indexname=PK_mytable id=lock621a0ce00 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057594046119936
2020-06-02 09:50:07.020 spid32s     owner-list
2020-06-02 09:50:07.020 spid32s      owner id=process61c7804e8 mode=U
2020-06-02 09:50:07.020 spid32s     waiter-list
2020-06-02 09:50:07.020 spid32s      waiter id=process614a23088 mode=U requestType=wait
2020-06-02 09:50:07.020 spid32s    keylock hobtid=72057594046119936 dbid=5 objectname=mydb.myschema.mytable 
indexname=PK_mytable id=lock61807a800 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057594046119936
2020-06-02 09:50:07.030 spid32s     owner-list
2020-06-02 09:50:07.030 spid32s      owner id=process614a23088 mode=U
2020-06-02 09:50:07.030 spid32s     waiter-list
2020-06-02 09:50:07.030 spid32s      waiter id=process61c7804e8 mode=U 
requestType=wait
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that two different processes hold the update lock on PK_mytable at the same time.

One session *owns* the lock, the other is *waiting* on the lock.

2020-06-02 09:50:07.020 spid32s     **owner**-list
2020-06-02 09:50:07.020 spid32s      owner id=process61c780**4e8** mode=U

2020-06-02 09:50:07.020 spid32s     waiter-list
2020-06-02 09:50:07.020 spid32s      waiter id=process614a23**088** mode=U requestType=**wait**

Each session owns one lock and is waiting for a lock owned by the other session.

lock621a0ce00 is owned by process61c7804e8 and process614a23088 is waiting for it.

lock61807a800 is owned by process614a23088 and process61c7804e8 is waiting for it.

Comment: Yep.  Two different key locks on the same table.  Each lock owned by one session, and waited for by the other session.  Vanilla deadlock.